How do the Fremen harvest spice?
In Frank Herbert's Dune, the people who are native to the Planet Arrakis are known as "Fremen".
Whilst the planet Arrakis is under imperial rule, the Fremen have certain freedoms which they have hard-fought for.
One of the ways they've fought for that freedom is by having bribed the Space Guild to keep any and all satellites out:

Jessica stopped in the act of turning away from him, looked back up into his face. “The Guild? What has the Guild to do with your spice?”
“It’s Liet’s command,” Stilgar said. “We know the reason, but the taste of it sours us. We bribe the Guild with a monstrous payment in spice to keep our skies clear of satellites and such that none may spy what we do to the face of Arrakis.”

Additionally, the Fremen use the spice in virtually everything, in their drinks, their foods, their rituals.
I can understand those smaller portions, given how abundant the spice is within Arrakis. What I don't understand is how they harvest such "monstrous amounts" so to be able to effectively bribe the Guild.
Now, when we look at the harvesting mechanics that goes on when the Harkonnen/Atreides harvest the spice, it's a very significant operation - involving large machinery and they constant threat of interruption from Shai-Hulud.

How do the Fremen extract/harvest so much spice on Arrakis?
I'm not saying they can't do it, they obviously do; I'm just interested in the how.

Remember the Fremen aren't primitive. They manufacture stillsuits which are widely recognised as the best, which indicates a high command of technology.

It is suggested in Children of Dune that the Fremen also use, or did use before Paul, massive mechanical harvesters in the south where no-one could see them. Leto II goes to a smuggler base, built by off-worlders but taken over by the Fremen later. Due to the lack of off-worlder exploitation, because of the strong Fremen presence in the southern deserts, the spice fields of the south are fabulously rich and the Fremen's knowledge of the desert means they don't often lose equipment or harvester time to worms etc...

But no one saw them because there were no satellites. How did they get enought spice to get that started?

@FlaStorm32 It's not that the Guild requires such a large bribe, but that they have the power to demand it. One imagines that they may have started small, and kept asking for more as production ramped up--or even helped invest in production directly! One might imagine the Guild rather likes having so reliable a source of spice, which they can hold a sword over the head of without too many worries about imperial politics.

In Heretics of Dune, the Fremen have largely returned to their old ways of living. The children of the villages regularly travel to where the worms have passed, in order to collect (by hand) the spice that is turned up by their passage.

That morning—much like this morning, the night’s chill sharp in her nose and lungs, the horizon constricted by a ghostly haze—most of the village children had fanned out into the desert, there to seek bits and fragments of melange, which Shaitan sometimes left behind in his passage. Two big ones had been heard nearby in the night. Melange, even at modern deflated prices, could buy the glazed bricks to line a third windtrap.

When you have a million-strong army of workers, happy to spend an entire day doing a single activity, you wouldn't need specialised equipment to generate considerable quantities of Spice. You just have large numbers of people go and collect it the hard way, piece by mind-numbing piece.

Spice harvesting effectively means filtering it out of spice heavy desert sand. The large spice harvesters do this using mechanical sifts, there is no reason to assume the Fremen couldn't have used similar methods in a more labour intensive (and slower) way using tools as primitive as buckets, spades, and hand held sifts.
And of course it has been described in the books that the Fremen operated spice harvesters captured from the Harkonen and other enemies, but those would not have existed when the spice harvest started initially (the investment needed for them indicate that the high profit margin of the spice was known before their design even started).
If we go from the way sifting grain from chaff developed on Earth, we'd see at the start hand held devices, then hand powered mechanical devices, possibly draft animals after that (though the books don't mention any of those on Arakis, so that stage may have been skipped), then ever larger motorised contraptions until arriving at the era described in the books, with large fully mechanised self propelled machines being used (which as described work similar to combine harvesters we have for harvesting grains).
The books to the best of my knowledge do not describe the deep history of the spice harvest, so speculation based on similar processes we do know is about all we can do.
